# Sub Select Inside UPDATE

Tags: sql

I have two tables, one called *'guilds'*, and one called *'guild_colours'*. The fields within *guild_colours* are *id*, and *colour* (I.E: 1:FFFFFF, 2:000000..), the table *guilds* has to contain the hex value for the colour. As the available colours inside of *guilds_colours* are ever changing (however previously available colours are acceptable).

I need to run an UPDATE query when a user decides to change the colour of their guild. I started coming up with something like this

```
    UPDATE guilds g
    SET g.primarycolour = (SELECT colour FROM  guild_colours WHERE id = ? ),                                 
    g.secondarycolour = (SELECT colour FROM guild_colours WHERE id = ?)
    WHERE g.id = ?
```

I was wondering if there's anything faster that I could do?

Comment: What does `id` in guild_colours refer to? If it's just a color identifier, there's no need to even have a join if you validate the colors against the list and given your rule that "previously available colours are acceptable".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE guilds AS g 
SET g.primarycolour = (
    SELECT c.colour FROM table_name AS c 
    WHERE c.id = 1
), g.secondarycolour = (
    SELECT c.colour FROM table_name AS c
    WHERE c.id = 2
)
WHERE g.id = 1
```

Note: I didn't test it though.

Comment: Yeah, i've come up with something similar (see the original post). Just like to double check the things i'm doing are the most efficient they can be. :P